# GCE doesn't deploy GCR image correctly

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

I have followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) from Google documentation in order to be able to push a custom Docker image to Google Container Registry and then be able to start a new GCE instance with this image. At first I wanted to try using an [anaconda3 public image](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3/) from docker hub without any modification (in order to test).

So here is the steps I have done so far after installing gcloud and docker:

1. `gcloud auth configure-docker` -> configured docker with my gcloud crendentials
2. `docker pull continuumio/anaconda3` -> pulled the public image
3. `docker tag continuumio/anaconda3 eu.gcr.io/my-project-id/anaconda3` -> tagged the local image with the registry name as specified in the doc
4. `docker push eu.gcr.io/my-project-id/anaconda3` -> pushed the image to GCR

Good ! I am now able to see my image trough GCR interface, and also able to deploy it with GCE. I choose to deploy it with a **f1-micro** instance, **Container-Optimized OS 67-10575.62.0 stable, 10 Go** boot disk, Allow HTTP traffic, etc.

But when I connect with `ssh` to the freshly new created VM instance, I can't find anaconda3 librairies (which are supposed to be created in `/opt/conda`). Instead, I can see a `/opt/google` directory which makes me think that the image has not been deployed correctly and GCE is using a default image...

So I tried to check if the image was pushed correctly in GCR, so I decided to delete my local image and pull it once again from GCR:

1. `docker rmi -f eu.gcr.io/my-project-id/anaconda3`
2. `docker pull eu.gcr.io/my-project-id/anaconda3:latest`

I run the image

`docker run -t -i eu.gcr.io/my-project-id/anaconda3`

and I can see that everything is fine, I have anaconda3 installed correctly inside `/opt/conda` with all the toolts needed (Pandas, Numpy, Jupyter notebook, etc.)

---

I tried to find people with the same problem as me without any success... maybe I have done something wrong in my proccess ?
Thanks !

**TL;DR** My problem is that I have pushed an anaconda3 image on Google GCR, but when I launch a virtual instance with this image, I do not have anaconda on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's normal that you can't find anaconda libraries installed directly on the GCE instance.

Actually, when you choose to deploy a container image on a GCE VM instance, a Docker container is started from the image you provide (in your example, `eu.gcr.io/my-project-id/anaconda3`). The libraries are not installed on the host, but rather **inside** that container (run `docker ps` to see it, but normally it has the same name as your VM instance). If you run something like :

```
docker exec -it <docker_container_name> ls /opt/conda
```

Then you should see the anaconda libraries, **only existing inside the container**.

When you run `docker run -t -i eu.gcr.io/my-project-id/anaconda3`, you're actually starting the container and running an interactive bash session inside that container (see the [`CMD` here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/blob/master/anaconda3/Dockerfile#L30)). That's why you can find anaconda libraries : you are inside the container!

Containerization software (`docker` here) provides isolation between your host and your containers. I'll suggest you to read documentation about [containerization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization), [Docker](https://www.docker.com/what-container) and [how to run containers on Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-container-instance).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, deploying a GCR container image to GCE is like using docker on a classic linux distribution, and pull & run the image I want from docker hub, is that it?

But when I run `docker ps` I can find a container using `gcr.io/gce-containers/konlet:v.0.8-latest` image, and when I run `docker exec -it <container_id> ls /opt` nothing is printed.
If I run `docker images` I can only see the konlet image, it seems I can't find the anaconda3 image..

Anyway thanks for the clarification, it was very useful ! Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to upvote yet haha

Comment: @Sewake You're right, using this method it avoids you to install Docker by yourself; moreover, Container-Optimized OS have many [benefits](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits). [Konlet](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/konlet) container should only shows up at VM startup, its goal is just to start your own container, based on what you set on `gce-container-declaration` (or in the Web UI). It's then stopped once your own container is up. But it's weird that your own container does not appear. Maybe `f1-micro` is too small?